# Is base 64 encoding with a secret key of strings, a possible way of Protection?

Tags: php, security, post, get

i am reading that in a paper

**Any end-user could modify these values (since they are originated in his browser), but if the web developer encodes for example, converting all characters to URL-encoding (hexadecimal) or uses a particular encoding to send GET/POST parameters (e .g., base64 with some secret key string) the attack vector must be revisited.**

so, this means that is good practice encoding the variables with base 64 and a secret key? 
how is implemented an url-encoding?

this makes sense? i never read about encoding variables as a way of protection

thanks

[paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.135&rep=rep1&type=pdf) page 5

Comment: I can see how Base64 encoding data from the server to the client, or server to server could be done with a bit of security/obscurity, but if your going from the client (aka: Browser) to the Server then everything is insecure and visible/accessible to the malicious attackers.  You might be able to generate a hash or insert some bits you verify/compare against the user using the form.  If you want to protect from people who are capturing data, you should use SSL.

Comment: base64 encoding does not use keys

Comment: Sadly Base64 is not security related. If you want in depth reasons and discussion, feel free to migrate this over to security.stackexchange.com where this question is definitely on-topic

Comment: It looks like the author is mixing encryption and base64-encoding here. Base64 has no key, and simply using base64 will not avoid the SQL-injection attack, only make it a tiny little bit harder (i.e. the attacker can't simply modify the URI in the browser's address line, but has to use a software which encodes the attack text to base 64 first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Base64** encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data (like HTTP). This is to ensure that the data remains intact without modification during transport.

So yes it can be ***a way of protecting*** the original data form unwanted modification. But remember it is ***not*** anywhere near ***Encryption***.

---

The specification for URLs [(RFC 1738, Dec. '94](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)) poses a problem, in that it limits the use of allowed characters in URLs to only a limited subset of the US-ASCII character set:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL."

Here's  nice article on that http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

In PHP you can use [**`string urlencode ( string $str )`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method for URL Encoding.

Comment: and about that? URL-encoding (hexadecimal)? how this is made in a php way?

Answer (score 3):

> so, this means that is good practice
>   encoding the variables with base 64
>   and a secret key? how is implemented
>   an url-encoding?
>
> this makes sense?

No, it doesn't really make sense.  **base64** is not an encryption scheme, it's just a way of encoding binary data into a subset of 7-bit text that isn't likely to be altered by email servers, etc.

base64 does not have a key, not can it encrypt or decrypt.

My guess is that the paper's authors were talking about some encryption scheme prior to the bit you quoted, and they only mentioned base64 later as a way to transmit their already encrypted data safely over HTTP GET or POST parameters.

Without seeing the rest of what you quoted from, we don't know.

Answer (score 2):

base 64 encode does not provide any security whatsoever. it is almost as bad as a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher

here's how to encode/decode in base 64, also known as radix64
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

im not sure what it means to encode with a key in this context